# How can I optimize the groupby.apply(function) in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, collections, deque

I have a function that uses deque.collections to track daily stock in based on FIFO. An order will be fulfilled if possible and is substracted from stock accordingly. I use a function in groupby.apply(my_function).

I have struggles where to place the second loop. Both loops work properly when run on their own. But I do not get them working combined.

The dataset is about 1.5 million rows.
Thanks.

```
DOS = 7
WIP = 1

df_fin['list_stock'] = 0
df_fin['stock_new'] = 0

def create_stocklist(x):
    x['date_diff'] = x['dates'] - x['dates'].shift()
    x['date_diff'] = x['date_diff'].fillna(0)
    x['date_diff'] = (x['date_diff'] / np.timedelta64(1, 'D')).astype(int)
    x['list_stock'] = x['list_stock'].astype(object)
    x['stock_new'] = x['stock_new'].astype(object)

    var_stock = DOS*[0]
    sl = deque([0],maxlen=DOS)

    for i in x.index:

        order = x['order_bin'][i]

        if x['date_diff'][i] > 0:
            for p in range(0,x['date_diff'][i]):
                if p == WIP:
                    sl.appendleft(x.return_bin[i-1])
                else:
                    sl.appendleft(0)

                sl_list = list(sl)
                sl_list.reverse()

                new_list = []

#from here the loop does not work as I wanted it to work. 
#I want to loop over de created sl_list
#and then start the loop above with the outcome of the loop below.

            for elem in sl_list:
                while order > 0:
                    val = max(0,elem-order)
                    order = (abs(min(0,elem-order)))
                    new_list.append(val)
                    break

                else:
                    new_list.append(elem)

            new_list.reverse()
            x.at[i,'list_stock'] = new_list

            sl = deque(new_list)

    return x

df_fin.groupby(by=['ID']).apply(create_stocklist)
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have access to `sl_list` inside the second loop, you should just define it in the upper scope: for example just after the first global for loop:

```
for i in x.index:
        # define it just here
        sl_list = []
        order = x['order_bin'][i]
```